# y-shift every second xtick

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with overlapping xticks. I have to fit way too many xticks in my plot, and every tick is a meaningful string, so I cannot leave some out. I have already rotated the xticks by 90° with

```
axis.tick_params(axis ='x', rotation = -90)
```

and I found a solution to give all major xticks a y-shift:

```
axis.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=10)
```

Unfortunately, all of my ticks are major ticks, and I don't know how to resolve this. In the end I want every second xtick shifted in y-direction, so that the ticks do not overlap any more.

I am not allowed to share the full code with you, but here is a snippet of what it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: can you add the code you used to generate the figure, and the figure?

Comment: Here is an approach using the minor ticks to get odd and even labels at a different height: [How to obtain xticks with alternating distances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354147/how-to-obtain-xticks-with-alternating-distances/61354709#61354709).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) together with a [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) object

```
In [49]: import numpy as np 
    ...: import matplotlib 
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    ...: from itertools import cycle 
    ...: %matplotlib tk 
    ...:  
    ...: format_cycle = cycle(['% 3.1f', '% 10.1f', '% 17.1f', '% 10.1f']) 
    ...: @matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter 
    ...: def major_formatter(x,pos): return next(format_cycle)%x                          

In [50]: fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
    ...: t = np.linspace(0,6.28, 629) 
    ...: ax.plot(t, np.sin(t)) 
    ...: ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,6.3, 0.1)) 
    ...: ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=-90) 
    ...: ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_formatter) 
    ...: fig.tight_layout()                                                               

In [51]:
```

[image]

In your use case you already have the labels? and so it's just a matter of prepending them with an appropriate number of spaces before passing them to `ax.set_xticklabels`

```
spaces = cycle(['', '   ', '      ', '   ']) # 0, 3, 6, 3 spaces
ax.set_xticklabels([next(spaces)+label for label in labels])
```